# Creating a listener for UserSessions (CUBA Studio)

Tags: java, cuba-platform

I am creating a project on the CUBA Studio platform (Java). I will be grateful for tips and useful links.

I have the MyUser extends User class, the field lastTimeOnline has been added. I want to implement the update of this field through the UserSession (activation and deactivation). The UserSession itself is not saved in the database.

Cuba Studio has a UserSessionListener interface that I would like to implement, but I can't figure out how to activate this listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Spring listeners for authentication events provided by CUBA.
E.g. for tracking a successful login, implement a Spring bean:

```
@Component
public class LoginEventListener {

    @EventListener
    protected void onUserLoggedIn(UserLoggedInEvent event) {
        User user = event.getUserSession().getUser();
        // ...
    }
}
```

More info here: https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-7.2/login.html#login_events

Though I am not sure if corresponding event exists for session expiration.

Comment: Thank you for the information!
Yes, I have read about these listeners, but, as I understand it, this method does not take into account the duration of further work in sessions and registers only the moment of authorization.
I was interested in the UserSessionListener interface because of its description, and I would like to know how to implement it:
 * Implementors receive notification when the user session changes.
 * This notification is useful for discontinuing a costly animation, or indicating that the user is no longer present on a network service.

Comment: If you mean interface from the java.awt.desktop package, then it is a part of the Java's desktop UI library, and it cannot be used for web apps.
BTW you can override the com.haulmont.cuba.security.app.UserSessionLogBean Spring bean in your project, it receives notifications even about expiring sessions (SessionAction.TERMINATION).